# Spoilers are showing in the Hot Network Questions on Stackoverflow

Tags: support, hot-questions, spoilers

The questions along the side need spoiler alerts if they relate to movie/tv series plot lines:

[screenshot http://imageshack.com/a/img801/5641/chuz.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img801/5641/chuz.png)

See the Game of Thrones question

Comment: That's because only the titles are shown; we cannot hide parts of titles. Short of making it a site rule to not allow spoilers in titles we cannot do anything about this, really.

Comment: Maybe the site rule is the way to go then. The strength of SO is the self policing community.

Comment: That isn't really a spoiler, it's about something that happened before the plot even started.

Comment: Ral - that's a good point actually - I'd completely forgotten that!

Comment: FWIW, I'm on here today and trying to avoid looking at HNQ because I've already seen 3 spoilers in it, I think. I'm trying to avoid thinking about them. Ironically one was seen whilst looking for a way to avoid more.